# update and save xml node

Tags: c#, .net, xml

hello I have this xml code

```
    <AriaGostarInformation>
  <MenuInformation>
    <MenuNames Name="1">
      home
    </MenuNames>
    <MenuNames Name="2">
      pages
    </MenuNames>
    <MenuNames Name="3">
      blog
    </MenuNames>
    <MenuNames Name="4">
      gallery
    </MenuNames>
    <MenuNames Name="5">
      about us
    </MenuNames>
    <MenuNames Name="6">
    contact us
    </MenuNames>
    <SubMenuNames parentName="1">
      fgfgfgfgs
    </SubMenuNames>
    <SubMenuNames parentName="3">
    </SubMenuNames>
  </MenuInformation>
</AriaGostarInformation>
```

and c# code:

```
public void updateXmlNodeWithAttribute(string XmlNodeName, string XmlAttributeName, List<string> XmlNodeAttribute, List<string> XmlNodeValue)
{
    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.Load(_connection);
    XmlNodeList xnode = getXmlNodeList(XmlNodeName);

    for (int i = 0; i < XmlNodeAttribute.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode item in xnode)
        {
            if (item.Attributes[XmlAttributeName].Value == XmlNodeAttribute[i].ToString())
            {
                item.InnerText = XmlNodeValue[i].ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    xdoc.Save(_connection);
}
```

The getXmlNodeList method return Specified xmlnodelist from XML file

This code does not throw an error, but DOES NOT update the XML node.

```
public XmlNodeList getXmlNodeList(string XmlNodeName)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(_connection);
    XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName(XmlNodeName);
    return elemList;
}
```

Please help me where is error in my code?

Comment: Post all code, including `getXmlNodeList`. Does the inner loop execute at least once? Does the innermost `if` ever match? Did you step it in debugger, does the assignment executes at least once?

Answer (score 1):

I found two problems in your code.

The first error is in your `for` loop. With -1 the last element in the List is always not used. Or if you only have one element in your list the `for` loop is never executed.

The second problem is, that you load the XML file twice. First time you load it in the updateXmlNodeWithAttribute method. Second time you load it in the getXmlNodeList method.

You must know that each loaded XML Document is independent from other loaded XML Document.
So what your code does is you get a List with XML Nodes from your XML file loaded in the getXmlNodeList Method, edit one of these XML Nodes and then you try to save the XML Document loaded in the updateXmlNodeWithAttribute method where no changes were made because the two XML Documents are completely independent.

So what you have to do is use the same XmlDocument object in both methods.
See the code below.

```
public static void updateXmlNodeWithAttribute(string XmlNodeName, string XmlAttributeName, List<string> XmlNodeAttribute, List<string> XmlNodeValue)
    {
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.Load(_connection);
        XmlNodeList xnode = getXmlNodeList(XmlNodeName,xdoc);

        for (int i = 0; i < XmlNodeAttribute.Count; i++)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode item in xnode)
            {
                if (item.Attributes[XmlAttributeName].Value == XmlNodeAttribute[i].ToString())
                {
                    item.InnerText = XmlNodeValue[i].ToString();
                }
            }
        }

        xdoc.Save(_connection);
    }

    public static XmlNodeList getXmlNodeList(string XmlNodeName, XmlDocument doc)
    {
        XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName(XmlNodeName);
        return elemList;
    }
```